# OAuth2 Implicit Flow with C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, implicit-flow, oidc-client

I'm developing a c# windows forms app that needs to authenticate using the Implicit Flow (The client does not accept another flow). As requirement, I need to open the default system browser to authenticate (so no embedded web view on the application)

I'm trying to use the [OidcClient C#](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient) and the [Samples](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples) but I can't get it to work.

The closest I got was using the `ConsoleSystemBrowser`. But using the code below I get always an `UnknownError` with `empty response`.

I can see in the browser the id_token: `http://127.0.0.1:54423/auth/signin-oidc#id_token=XXX`. How can I read it?

```
        var browser = new SystemBrowser();
        var redirectUri = string.Format($"http://127.0.0.1:{browser.Port}/auth/signin-oidc");

        var options = new OidcClientOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://demo.identityserver.io",
            ClientId = "implicit",
            Scope = "openid profile api",
            RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            Browser = browser
        };

        var client = new OidcClient(options);
        var state = await client.PrepareLoginAsync(new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { OidcConstants.AuthorizeRequest.ResponseType, OidcConstants.ResponseTypes.IdTokenToken}
        });

        var browserOption = new BrowserOptions(state.StartUrl, redirectUri)
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300),
            DisplayMode = DisplayMode.Hidden,
            ResponseMode = OidcClientOptions.AuthorizeResponseMode.Redirect
        };

        var result = await browser.InvokeAsync(browserOption, default);

        result.ResultType => BrowserResultType.UnknownError
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application should register a private URL `scheme` with the networking component of the OS. Then, URLs of the form "x-my-app://xxx" will be forwarded to your application. (And you register the URL with the OAuth IdP so it works as a redirect URL.)

For Windows, it appears that Microsoft calls this "Pluggable Protocols". See

- [programming-pluggable-protocols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/programming-pluggable-protocols)
- [An older doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

A source of code examples for this pattern might be from the github desktop application--it is open source and registers its own scheme with Windows.

It registers the private scheme `x-github-client` You can see how it's done in the [source](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/blob/006d191eeb09792f1b4c4c7112780a2a018fb941/app/src/main-process/main.ts#L96) also see [here](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/commit/1f73294e146ba69220f4c0479deea393e7d58b2b)